# Phrase "In my spare time"

Tags: phrase-requests

In an office environment answering a customer with the response "I will work on your project in my spare time". I feel there is a more professional way to answer. Suggestions?

Comment: I'll work an answer into my schedule.

Comment: I'll write the request down on an PostIt and file it the bottom drawer of my filing cabinet.

Comment: Your project has been prioritized below any of my real work but I will try to work on it whenever I have nothing else to do.   (The point is, telling your customer that you will work on it in your spare time is probably not what they want to hear; unless they were expecting you to not be able to work on it at all)

Comment: What @Jim said. Besides which, in my experience some customers think you can't be working hard enough if you even admit to *having* any "spare time". In any event, it's not really "professional" to offer to do any work outside your normal paid activities.

Comment: ...having said that, *"I will work on your project **as time permits**"* is probably one of the least "dismissive" ways to put it.

Comment: Or, "I'll see if I can find time for it."  A lot depends on what impression you want to give:  Are you expecting to get to it shortly, just not on a predictable schedule, or is it not reasonably certain that the task will get done at all, at least not in this century?

Answer (score 2):

the phrase "I will work on your project as soon as possible" might be appropriate.

Comment: +1 I quite like that, _as soon as possible_ could well be next year but it sounds like you are keen.

Comment: +1 Great idea. Why didn't I think of that?!

Answer (score 1):

Using the phrase "when I get a moment" might be appropriate. It implies that the task will be completed, if not at that exact time:

> "I will work on your project when I get a moment"

As suggested in the comments, I also think mentioning working it into your schedule is a tactful way of getting your message across:

> "I will work on your project as my schedule permits"